# adding to icollection in viewmodel

Tags: c#

I have an ICollection in my 'UserViewModel':

```
public ICollection<userpractice> userpractices { get; set; }
```

In my controller I am trying to add a userpractice to this collection in the viewmodel:

```
user user = db.users.Find(id);
UserViewModel uservm = new UserViewModel();

foreach (var up in user.userpractices)
{
    uservm.userpractices.Add(up);
}
```

I get an error saying 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' I dont know why because the up is definitely correctly assigned to a populated userpractice.

uservm.userpractices is null if that helps. But I think that should be null at first as the viewmodel doesnt have any userpractices in the collection!

Comment: That's because you haven't created an instance of a collection yet, update your `UserViewModel` constructor to do `this.userpractices = new List<userpractice>()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly normal that `uservm.userpractices` is `null` at first. That's why you need to create a new instance of the collection before adding items to it. Example:

```
List<string> items;
items.Add("test"); //Object reference exception
```

First do this:

```
items = new List<string>();
items.Add("test"); //works
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, didn't have to ask my question because of this answer.